# PHP code doesn't remove a table whereas a raw sql does

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress 5.3

I'm writing a plugin thif method removes the database table.
When I put a breakpoint in this function and execute the copied value of $sql, the table is been really removed. But this very code doesn't remove the table. Could you help me here?

```
public function deactivate(){
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    $sql = "drop table if exists $this->table_name;";
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you have proper value in $this->table_name ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$sql = "drop table if exists ".$this->table_name.";";
```

or this:

```
$sql = "drop table if exists {$this->table_name};";
```